# graphing scatter for ranges in python's matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this graph so far, it's kind of ugly. Each type of marker is an accuracy for a type of algorithm.

[image: scatter plot]

There are two problems with this:

1. I'd like there to be space between the content and the axises, but only show ticks for y [0, 1] and have the x axis show no negative values (no such thing as negative time).
2. I'd like to display the x values as their log transform, but keep the original values on the ticks so you can see the actual values.

For #1 I tried playing with xticks as you can see below but without much success.

For #2, it's simple to throw the data into an `np.log10()` but then the axis ticks are also log transformed. I feel like there should be a simple way to do this log display (seems like a pretty normal thing to do)?

Here's my code so far:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

# create fake data
data = {}
data['A'] = []
data['B'] = []
data['C'] = []

n = 5
data['A'] = zip(np.random.uniform(0, 10000, size=n), np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, size=n))
data['B'] = zip(np.random.uniform(0, 200, size=n), np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, size=n))
data['C'] = zip(np.random.uniform(0, 5000, size=n), np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, size=n))

# make graph
markers = ['+', '*', 'x']
colors = ['b', 'r', 'g']
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plots = []
labels = []

# extract data
i = 0
for algorithm in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    results = data[algorithm]
    testing = np.array([float(x[1]) for x in results if x > 0.0])
    ts = np.array([int(x[0]) for x in results if x > 0.0])
    color = colors[i]
    marker = markers[i]
    plot = ax1.scatter(ts, testing, color=color, marker=marker, s=10)
    plots.append(plot)
    labels.append(algorithm)
    i += 1

# set axis and title
ax1.legend(plots, labels, loc='lower right')
ax1.set_xlabel("Time (sec)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Testing Accuracy")
ax1.set_title("Time versus testing accuracy")

# set axis limits
xticks, xticklabels = plt.xticks()
xmin = (3*xticks[0] - xticks[1])/2.
xmax = (3*xticks[-1] - xticks[-2])/2.
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.xticks(xticks)

plt.ylim(0.0, 1.0)

# save to disk
plt.savefig("scatter.eps")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you are not doing this?

```
ax1.set_ylim( -.1, 1.1 )
ax1.set_yticks( np.linspace(0, 1, 10) )

ax1.set_xscale('log')
```